# How do I calculate a webm's duration metadata value as hex?

Tags: webm

I basically want to take a time value, convert it into a hexadecimal format value that the webm metadata can read.

Here is an example value:
`44 89 88 40 D5 51 C0 00 00 00 00` = `00:00:21.831000000`

How would I calculate this, can you provide examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a 64-bit Double, can be calculated with this: [binaryconvert](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=052056048048048)
Input example: 48000 would be 48 seconds flat. 100000 would be 1 minute 40 seconds. Etc.
Output as hex is shown when you convert as binary and read the left side on the site's output.